# onTouchListener not working

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have the following code in my activity. In my xml, the video view is inside the linear layout. However, when the view is clicked, the `onTouchListener` never fires. I tried changing the `onTouchListener` to `vvLive` but that didn't do anything. I also tried changing the `onTouchListener` to an `onClickListener`, but nothing. Anyone know why the listener isn't firing? Thanks.

```
        private VideoView vvLive;
        LinearLayout linearLayoutLiveVideo;

        linearLayoutLiveVideo.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch entered");
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP");

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**EDIT**: 
I realized the code above actually works. Something in eclipse was messing up LogCat. After I restarted eclipse, LogCat prints the first log "onTouch entered". However, "ACTION_UP" was not being printed. I changed the MotionEvent to `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and the LogCat prints now. Why does `ACTION_DOWN` work but `ACTION_UP` does not?

Comment: Are these views the ones that are being displayed in your activity?

Comment: does "clicable" property of layout set to true?

Comment: @woodshy adding clickable=true did not do anything

Comment: @dmon yes, I am playing a video inside a VideoView vvLive which is inside of a LinearLayout linearLayoutLiveVideo. I want to do some action when the user touches the video that is playing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

ACTION_UP is never being sent to your listener because you return false and therefor don't "consume" the event. Return true and you'll get the start event (ACTION_DOWN) as well as all the subsequent ones (ACTION_MOVE and then ACTION_UP).

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code like this and try:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch entered");
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP");
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What about the setOnTouchListener. Can I still use that?

Comment: Yes you have to use that line. Replace the lines below it as I have given and try it.

Comment: `Error: The type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnTouchListener.onTouch(View, MotionEvent)`. It looks like I cant use onTouchListner with onTouchEvent?

Comment: onTouchEvent  not in fragment

Answer (score 1):

i have faces this issue and the solutions is:-

1-in your xml set the followin attribute to VideoView

android:clickable="true"

2- simply in your code set setOnClickListenerto the VideoView and it will work like charm:

```
videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(CinemaDetailsActivity.this , FullScreenPlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("url" ,  getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```